# Python3 cross compilation for openwrt on Lenovo newifi

Tags: python, linux, cross-compiling, openwrt

Since the Python3 in openwrt 15.05 does not include the pip3,
so I want to build another Python3 with version Python3.4.3 for openwrt.

I used this configuration:

```
./configure --host=mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=$PWD/prefix CC=mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc-gcc RANLIB=mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc-ranlib AR=mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc-ar LD=mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc-ld --disable-ipv6 ac_cv_file__dev_ptmx=no ac_cv_file__dev_ptc=no
```

Also I created a Python3.4.3/prefix for installation.

The configuration and make succeeded, but make install failed.

The message shown was like this:

```
make install
...
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/newifi1505/openwrt1505/source/Python-3.4.3/Lib/runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main 
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "/home/newifi1505/openwrt1505/source/Python-3.4.3/Lib/runpy.py", line  85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/home/newifi1505/openwrt1505/source/Python-3.4.3/Lib/ensurepip/__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ensurepip._main()
File "/home/newifi1505/openwrt1505/source/Python-3.4.3/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 209, in _main
default_pip=args.default_pip,
File "/home/newifi1505/openwrt1505/source/Python-3.4.3/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 116, in bootstrap
_run_pip(args + [p[0] for p in _PROJECTS], additional_paths)
File "/home/newifi1505/openwrt1505/source/Python-3.4.3/Lib/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 40, in _run_pip
import pip
File "/tmp/tmp9drsnjlt/pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
File "/tmp/tmp9drsnjlt/pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 9, in <module>
File "/tmp/tmp9drsnjlt/pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/index.py", line 26, in <module>
File "/tmp/tmp9drsnjlt/pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/wheel.py", line 7, in <module>
File "/home/newifi1505/openwrt1505/source/Python-3.4.3/Lib/csv.py", line 7, in <module>
from _csv import Error, __version__, writer, reader, register_dialect, \
ImportError: /home/newifi1505/openwrt1505/source/Python-3.4.3/build/lib.linux-mipsel-3.4/_csv.cpython-34m.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

this ImportError was weird because I really have a _csv.cpython-34m.so in this directory, following are my stat and file output:

```
  # stat build/lib.linux-mipsel-3.4/_csv.cpython-34m.so
  File: ‘build/lib.linux-mipsel-3.4/_csv.cpython-34m.so’
  Size: 87616       Blocks: 176        IO Block: 4096   regular file
  Device: 803h/2051d    Inode: 970446      Links: 1
  Access: (0775/-rwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 1001/newifi1505)   Gid: ( 1001/newifi1505)
  Access: 2016-03-27 07:43:57.913889874 +0800
  Modify: 2016-03-27 07:42:25.481885655 +0800
  Change: 2016-03-27 07:42:25.481885655 +0800
  Birth: -

  # file build/lib.linux-mipsel-3.4/_csv.cpython-34m.so
  build/lib.linux-mipsel-3.4/_csv.cpython-34m.so: ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

I really can not understand why this happened...does anyone have idea about it?

Many thanks

Edit: In addition, I tried 3.4.4 and 3.5.1....but the error message is the same.

Comment: Python build system, AFAIR, does something extra during install: it tries to *import the fresh-built modules.* I don't remember their reason for doing that; but this behavior does occasionally break cross-compiled builds -- since the native .so modules won't import. I think there was a way to disable it.